# Different cores running at different frequencies while executing multithreaded benchmark

Tags: multithreading, architecture, multiprocessing

Consider One multithreaded benchmark is running on a chip multiprocessor. Changing the frequency of one core why affecting the execution time of others when each threads are running independently? Please explain

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory bandwidth below L1 cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Your answer makes sense. Do you think thread spawning also could be a factor?